# Can I compile qt 5.0 with the intel compiler on windows?

Tags: qt5, icc

I'm trying to compile Qt 5.0.1 from source using the intel compiler on windows.  Is such a thing possible?  I don't see, anywhere, how to select compilers for any platform, much less windows.

I've looked here:

[Building Qt5 from git](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git)

and here:

[Qt forums](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/25719)

Among other places, but those two are the closest I've come to an answer.

Comment: There's a win32-icc mkspec. Have you tried passing -mkspec win32-icc to configure?

Comment: where is that mkspec?  There's no mkspec that I can see in the qt 5 directories.  There is in the 4.8.4 directory.

Comment: Inside qtbase, see [here](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/trees/stable/mkspecs/win32-icc). If you're trying to compile qt5.git with its configure, just don't do it. Compile qtbase first then the other modules, in order.

Comment: @peppe-- I'll take a look.  Does it work, do you know?  I've been wrestling with 4.8.4 for the last two days.  Not least is that the configuration program switches to g++ for no apparent reason whatsoever.

Comment: The answer is, no, it does not work.  I'll have to make it work.  Very irritating, as right now the assistant isn't compiling in 4.8.4 because of missing qMain.